# Dropbox install problems on Scientific Linux

Tags: configure, dropbox

I am trying to install nautilus-dropbox-1.6.2.tar.bz2. I ran `./configure`, but got the error

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libnautilus-extension >= 2.16.0) were not met:

No package 'libnautilus-extension' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables NAUTILUS_CFLAGS
and NAUTILUS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I have done a google search for this, and found that some people suggested that one needs to download nautilus-devel. However, I have no idea what that is and how to download it. I google searched for it, and found it is for Fedora. I don't use Fedora.

Anyways, is that what I need to do? If not, then what else can I do?

Comment: what specific linux distro are you using?

Comment: Use your package manager for this...

Comment: I use scientific linux

Answer (score 11):

This would help remove the problem

```
sudo apt-get install libnautilus-extension-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you avoid compiling unless you have a specific and good reason for it.

The pre-compiled packages that you can find at [dropbox download site](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) should work right-out-of-the-box.

They can be installed using the package system for your distro (`dpkg` or `rpm`).

Scientific Linux is a RHEL derivative, so download the RPM from Dropbox, and run (as root):

```
 rpm -ihv <rpm-file-name>
```

Comment: The fedora RPM available from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) should probably work.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the nautilus-devel package should do the trick.

`yum install nautilus-devel`